# Add a button that scrolls with a UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a UIButton (or tappable UIView) appear above a UITableView. That is easy. The hard part is making it scroll when the user scrolls down the table view.

I have tried using a UIScrollView like so:

```
private var scroll = UIScrollView();
private var table = UITableView();

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scroll = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height));

    table = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height));
    table.register(ATableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier");
    table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0);
    table.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    table.separatorInset = .zero;
    table.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10);

    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    // table.estimatedRowHeight = 100;

    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;

    scroll.addSubview(table);

    self.view.addSubview(table);

}
```

The scrollbar space at the top can hold a button but will always be there. I want it to stay above the table view but be out of focus when the user scrolls down (like a web page or like the standard mail app in the iphone which does this with the search bar and a table view). Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried with `tableHeaderView`?

Comment: As in the header and footer of a UITableView? I have some sections but I don't want the header to stay there like it does.

Comment: How do I use the tableHeaderView? Thanks for your help.

Comment: couldnt you add the button in the first most cell of the table?

Comment: Set  your tableview style `Grouped` style then set `tableHeaderView` that will scroll with tableview.

Comment: @cdub as in Tableview's `TableHeadeView` not as in Tableview's Section headerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following 2 approaches to add a button above your tableview:

**1. Section Header:**

Add a section header in your top most section of your tableview. Do not forget to change the `UITableViewStyle` to `plain` or else the section header will stick on top.

**2. Table Header View:**

Add a `tableHeaderView` and place anything you want here. It will scroll as you scroll the tableview.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect scrolling of UITableView using delegate method, where you can set position of UIButton so it can move according to your UITableView scrolling.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView == myTableView){
   // Your code here.....
}
}
```